# Sprint boot custom exception not getting caught and response is always empty if error with status 200

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm struggling a lot with `spring-boot` custom exception handling. Customer exception is not getting caught with exception handler. REST API works fine for valid request payload. I'm trying to send error response when there's an error. But error response is always empty with status code 200 instead of 404.

`Controller`

```
package com.company.paypage.v2.controller;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.company.paypage.exception.*;
import com.company.paypage.model.ErrorMessageConstants;
import com.company.paypage.v2.model.ConfigPayload;
import com.company.paypage.v2.model.ConfigResponse;
import com.company.paypage.v2.services.FeatureConfigService;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "v2/setup")
public class FeatureConfigController {
    
     @Autowired
     private FeatureConfigService featureconfigService;

     /*
        features config endpoint
     */
     @RequestMapping(value = "/config", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ConfigResponse setupConfigRequest(@Valid @RequestBody ConfigPayload payload, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse servResponse) {
        log.info("Processing the feature config request for " + payload.getPage_type());
        ConfigResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = featureconfigService.processConfigRequest(payload);
            System.out.println(response);
            if(response == null) {
                throw new FeatureConfigException(ErrorMessageConstants.NOT_FOUND, "Error while generating feature config response.....");
            }
        } catch (FeatureConfigException e){
            log.error("Exception:",  e);
        }
        return response;
    } 
}
```

`Exception class`

```
package com.company.paypage.exception;

public class FeatureConfigException extends Exception {
    String code;
    String message;

    public FeatureConfigException(String code, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

`Exception handler`

```
package com.company.paypage.exception;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import com.company.paypage.model.ApplicationConstants;
import com.company.paypage.model.ErrorCodeConstants;
import com.company.paypage.model.ErrorMessageConstants;
import com.company.paypage.model.GeneralErrorInfo;
import com.company.paypage.model.Payment;
import com.company.paypage.model.SetupResponse;
import com.company.paypage.v2.model.ConfigResponse;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(FeatureConfigException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ConfigResponse> handleFeatureConfigException(FeatureConfigException ex, HttpServletRequest request){

        GeneralErrorInfo generalErrorInfo = new GeneralErrorInfo().withCode(ex.getCode());
        generalErrorInfo.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        String referenceId =(String) request.getAttribute(ApplicationConstants.REFERENCE_ID);
        ConfigResponse configResponse = buildConfigResponse(generalErrorInfo, referenceId);

        log.error("{} {}-{}"
                , ex.getMessage()
                , request.getHeader(ApplicationConstants.X_GP_REQUEST_ID)
                , referenceId
                , ex);  
        
        return new ResponseEntity<ConfigResponse>(configResponse, addCustomerHeaders(request), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    ConfigResponse buildConfigResponse(GeneralErrorInfo generalErrorInfo, String referenceId) {

        ConfigResponse configResponse = new ConfigResponse();
        configResponse.setError(generalErrorInfo);
        configResponse.setAutocomplete((Boolean) null);
        configResponse.setRefund((Boolean) null);
        configResponse.setSplit_payment((Boolean) null);
        configResponse.setTender_type(null);
        configResponse.setVoidd((Boolean) null);
        return configResponse;
    }

}
```

`ConfigResponse model`

```
package com.company.paypage.v2.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.company.paypage.model.GeneralErrorInfo;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "tender_type",
    "autocomplete",
    "split_payment",
    "refund",
    "void",
    "error"
})

public class ConfigResponse implements Serializable {
    
    @JsonProperty("tender_type")
    private TenderType tender_type;
    
    @JsonProperty("autocomplete")
    private boolean autocomplete;
    
    @JsonProperty("split_payment")
    private boolean split_payment;
    
    @JsonProperty("refund")
    private boolean refund;
    
    @JsonProperty("void")
    private boolean voidd;
    
    @JsonProperty("error")
    private GeneralErrorInfo error;

    public TenderType getTender_type() {
        return tender_type;
    }

    public void setTender_type(TenderType tender_type) {
        this.tender_type = tender_type;
    }

    public boolean isAutocomplete() {
        return autocomplete;
    }

    public void setAutocomplete(boolean autocomplete) {
        this.autocomplete = autocomplete;
    }

    public boolean isSplit_payment() {
        return split_payment;
    }

    public void setSplit_payment(boolean split_payment) {
        this.split_payment = split_payment;
    }

    public boolean isRefund() {
        return refund;
    }

    public void setRefund(boolean refund) {
        this.refund = refund;
    }

    public boolean isVoidd() {
        return voidd;
    }

    public void setVoidd(boolean voidd) {
        this.voidd = voidd;
    }
    
    public GeneralErrorInfo getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(GeneralErrorInfo error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public ConfigResponse withError(GeneralErrorInfo error) {
        setError(error);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**What could be the issue here? What am I missing to get proper error in `JSON` format in response?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the code of an exception. Here you can find different variants of how to handle exceptions for REST: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)